# Run an application that reads and writes external text files in java servlet

Tags: java, servlets, io

I am new to java servlet. I am writing an application that reads and writes text files. However, I am running this application on a java servlet using JSP. When I ran the servlet in eclipse, it keeps reporting file not found error. I really don't know how to correct the file path so that servlet won't complain about it.

Basically, the application and servlet code are in the same src folder, but different packages. Could you please tell me where I should place these text files and how I should read and write them? Thank you very much.

Comment: Answer these (files is a reference to the files that must be read by your servlet): 1. Where do the files reside; on the server or on the client desktop?  2. How are the files generated; uploaded to the server from client machines, created by a different application on the server, something else?  3.  Are the files that must be read the same as the files that must be written or are they different groups of files?

Comment: I am writing the servlet and the application in eclipse. I created a dynamic web project. I put all my text files that the application will read in WebContent folder together with all my JSP files.

Comment: @DwB For the second question, all the text files are pre-made by other programs. They are not created by a different application on the server. For the third question, all the files that must be read are text files while some output files are text files and some are json files.

Answer (score 1):

***Some Info***

- Files that are in a web applications context root are browsable by
  clients.  I suspect this is not a desired feature.
- Files that are under the WEB-INF folder in your web application are
  accessable to the web application, but are not browsable by clients.

***Suggested Solution 1***

- Plan to put the files in a folder under the WEB-INF folder; perhaps named "Files" (*i.e.* "WEB-INF/Files").
- Use [ServletContext.getRealPath()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html) to get the real file path.
- Read and write the files using java IO (BufferedReader, Scanner, something else - you choose).

***Sugested Solution 2***

Based on comments below.  The servlet will be part of a web application that is installed into a servlet container (maybe Tomcat) on a known host.  Create a directory on the host.  Add this directory to the servlet as a parameter (maybe servlet config, maybe a properties file, maybe a hard coded string, or any other solution).  Once this is done, the servlet will know where to read and write the files.  At that point, any application can read and write to the files in question.

No need to use getRealPath() with this solution, the real path is a parameter to the servlet.

***Suggested Reading List***

For an introduction (possibly dated, but still good), read the "Intermediate Servlets & JSP" and "Advanced Servlets & JSP" tutorials on the [Core Servlets](http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/csajsp2.html) website.

Another introduction source is the [Java EE 5 Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/).  The entire tutorial is good, but focus on Part II, chapters 3 and 4 for servlet information.  I prefer this tutorial to the [Java EE 6 Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/), but that may just be personal preference.

Comment: I tried to use ServletContext. However, since the application is in a different package, it could not identify ServletContext.

Comment: The servlet has access to the ServletContext.  The servlet should be calling into the reader/writer application.  The servlet can get the real path of the file and pass it to the application.

Comment: Is there a way that application can use to access these text files? Because some text file reading and writing are really independent of the servlet?

Comment: Could you be more specific about how I can add this directory to the servlet as a parameter and after that how to read these files from an application that is installed into the servlet? I have been searching online for several hours and still do not know how. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The default directory is the directory of your project.  Put your files in the project directory, for me it is "C:\Documents and Settings\myusername\workspace\projectname".

Answer (score 0):

You can place the file everywhere you want but i sugget to you to put it under WEB-INF so it can't be accessed directly.

You can access it using:

getServletContext().getRealPath("/WEB-INF/filename");

Comment: However, the problem is that the application is not a servlet itself and it is in a different package. I tried to use getServletContext, but the program does not identify it.